# Getting "read ECONNRESET" error for every Restfull Webservice calls

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kubernetes, econnreset

I've got a spring boot application deployed successfully on Kubernetes. But,  whenever I make a webservice call from Postman I receive "read ECONNRESET" error. My kubernetes pod and service are all up and running. I couldn't figure out the cause of the problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add more details to your question e.g. where is the Postman software? does it allow connections to the host/URI you are trying to reach? How is the Kubernetes Service exposed to the out side world? Also sharing the manifests files for your deployments will help users to answer your question better.

Comment: Thanks @Sibtain.  I've found the mistake.  I exposed the port 8081 for my service in Kubernetes yaml file  and  had forgotten to change the server port of springboot application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further explanation:

My service was exposing 8081 port as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-restapi
  namespace: restapi-k8s
  labels:
     app: restapi
spec:
  selector:
    app: restapi
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 32588
```

And my springboot application was running on port 8080. I've changed the server port of the application by adding the line below to my application.propereties file. Now problem is solved, my restfull web service is responding the requests from the port 8081.

```
server.port=8081
```